# Sum of Amount for each item in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have the code with different items like A,B,C,D and i want to calculate the sum of amount for each item 
 from the below query shows first item's amount whereas i want to get each item sum value

```
SELECT DISTINCT(itemname),sum(amount) FROM item
```

Comment: Post your table schema along with expected output

Comment: item name is like diesel,petrol,oil for each purchased item the amount stored in db i wants to display the sum of amount for each item like diesel - (total amount), petrol - (total amount), oil - (total amount)

Comment: Distinct is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try like this:

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
  FROM table
  GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: I want to use where condition after groupby is it possible?

Comment: yes it is possible you can add where clause before group by clause.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `GROUP BY` clause.

[Refer to mysql group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-handling.html)

Answer (score 0):

To get aggregated data you should use a `GROUP BY`. Try this:

```
 SELECT itemname, sum(amount) AS total
 FROM item
 GROUP BY itemname
```

This will group all rows by itemname and sum each groups amount into total.

*Note: this is simple SQL so it should work for most dialects, but in the future remember to state what DB you're using.*